# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error al hacer importador de archivo csv

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-for-backpack

Estoy haciendo un importador de archivos CSV para actualizar categorías en mi empresa.

Mientras intento procesarlo, Laravel me tira el siguiente error:

**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function procesar(ImportarCategoriasArticulos $importador){
    list( $ruta,$nombre_excel ) = explode('/', $importador->excel_ruta);
    ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
    //dd($importador);
    try{
        CategoriaArticulos::query()->truncate();
        Excel::import(new CategoriasArticulosImportador, public_path().'/storage/uploads/'.$nombre_excel);
        $articulos_no_encontrados = CategoriaArticulos::select(['codigo_interno'])->distinct()->whereNull('articulo_id')->get();
        if( $articulos_no_encontrados->count() > 0 ){
            $importador->articulos_no_encontrados = $articulos_no_encontrados->toJson();
            $importador->estatus = 'procesado con error';
            $importador->save();
            \Alert::error(trans('ERROR: Existen articulos no encontrados.'))->flash();
            return redirect('admin/configuracion/importar_categoria_articulos/'.$importador->id);
        } else {
            Articulo::all()->map( function( $articulo ){
                $nuevos_datos = CategoriaArticulos::where('articulo_id', $articulo->id)->first();
                $articulo->categoria = $nuevos_datos->categoria;
                $articulo->subcategoria = $nuevos_datos->subcategoria;
                $articulo->subsubcategoria = $nuevos_datos->subsubcategoria;
                $articulo->save();
            });

            \Artisan::command('key-a:sm:generar-categorias');
            $importador->estatus = 'procesado con exito';
            $importador->save();
            \Alert::success(trans('EXITO: se modificaron las categorias.'))->flash();
            return redirect('admin/configuracion/importar_categoria_articulos/');
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        \Alert::error(trans($e->getMessage()))->flash();
        return redirect('admin/configuracion/importar_categoria_articulos/');
    }
}
```

¿Sabrán qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En tu codigo tienes algun `foreach`?

Comment: De hecho no, por eso se me hace raro, pienso que quizá el error este en el ciclo IF pero no le encuentro nada malo al código